# Integrating existing Azure accounts with Azure AD

Tags: c#, .net, azure, msdn, azure-active-directory

My organisation has MSDN Premium subscriptions assigned to our developers, with each developer having a Microsoft account linked to the subscription.  The Microsoft accounts are associated with organisation email addresses i.e. *person@organisation.com*.  Several of the accounts are already being used to run VMs web apps etc.

We are now looking to install Azure AD Connect and sync our Active Directory with Azure, with a view to developing SSO applications where people would sign in as *person1@organisation.com*, *person2@organisation.com* and so on.  Registering the organisation's domain with Azure AD and installing Azure AD Connect looks to be a fairly straightforward task, but what I'm not sure of is:

- What happens to the existing *person@organisation.com* Microsoft accounts once we get Azure AD up and running?
- Do they automagically get associated with the Azure AD for the organisation?
- Are there any manual migration steps that must be done?  Or, will the existing accounts be orphaned?

Basically, I'm trying to understand what the implications are for existing applications and accounts once we flick the switch on Azure AD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> What happens to the existing person@organisation.com Microsoft
>   accounts once we get Azure AD up and running?

The Microsoft accounts are different from your orgnization's Azure AD account (OrgId/Work/School account). These Microsoft accounts are unrelated to the Org accounts and simply share the same email address but are hosted in completely different identity system.

> Do they automagically get associated with the Azure AD for the
>   organisation?

No, your individual users' work accounts and Microsoft accounts will have no technical connection in the backend.

> Are there any manual migration steps that must be done? Or, will the
>   existing accounts be orphaned?
>   MSDN accounts as of now do not support login with OrgId, only Microsoft accounts so you will have to continue to maintain them.

I recommend the following as a best practice -

Work account(s) used to provide access to Azure portal is preferred over Microsoft account(s) because of the following -

- Work account password policies can be set by company's IT team
- IT team can reset passwords of work account
- Azure AD reports will include info about sign-in/IP address/etc related to Work accounts, there is no such insight into Microsoft accounts.
- Access to various Azure subscriptions or other applications can be disabled by simply disabling the work account. Company has no real control over Microsoft account.
- Individual users get the benefit of SSO  when logged in to corporate AD using NTLM/Kerberos.

You will have to do the following to move people to use work accounts for Azure subscriptions

- Add every individual user's work account as service admin/co-admin/any other level to all the relevant subscription(s).
- Remove Microsoft accounts from all the roles/permissions to Azure services as far as possible (see next point)
- There are limitations in moving certain role(s) such as Account admin/Service admin as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/changing-service-admin-and-co-admin/).

Comment: This is a solid list of recommendations - thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

First, when you say "My organisation has MSDN Premium subscriptions assigned to our developers, with each developer having a  **Microsoft account** linked to the subscription" - Are these 'microsoft accounts' **individual Accounts** or **Work/School account** as MS calls them?

if they are **individual Accounts** then then they are not organisational accounts anyways and are not linked to your in-house AD, they just accounts with same email address. Actually we had to go through this already.

From Microsoft phone conversation - MSDN Azure subscriptions are for development purposes not for production. For production you need an Enterprise Agreement subscription or some other organisational offer. It would be this AZURE account that you will connect you AD to, not to the MSDN Azure subscriptions.

After that you can add those "MSDN" accounts as co-admins or users to the EA/Organisational subscription's AD.

Best thing to do is to give them a call. But that's how we are doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the Enterprise Agreement subscription information - this sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.  The existing Microsoft accounts are just individual accounts rather than work/school accounts and I'm aware that they're not linked to our organisation - I guess what I was hoping was that there would be a straightforward way of taking an individual account and converting/merging it into an organisation account!

Comment: MS can migrate you individual accounts, but you will loose the MSDN benefits. Basically how microsoft works is that you cannot combine two offers, in your case MSDN and EA. So its better to have your MSDN as it is on individual accounts and get a separate EA subscription for production stuff